# How can I implement advanced action routes (in routes.php)?

Tags: plugin-development, routes, routing

We want to mask specific action routes in our project's routes.php file. Currently what we have looks like this:

```
return array(
    // /actions/api/element/section/name/{$name}/
    'api/test/(?P<name>)'  => ['action' => 'api/element/section'],
);
```

We would like to pass name into the action array somehow. Is there something documented or undocumented that I'm missing? Or is what I'm attempting not possible at this time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it’s possible. First you will need to update your route key so that you’re capturing the `name` parameter with a valid [named subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php). (You were close, but missing the actual *pattern* part of it).

```
return array(
    'api/test/(?P<name>[^\/]+)' => ['action' => 'api/element/section'],
);
```

Any named subpattern matches in your route will be passed to your controller action’s `$variables` argument, if it has one.

```
class Api_ElementController extends BaseController
{
    // ...

    public function actionSection(array $variables = array())
    {
        $name = $variables['name'];

        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that you specifically need to call the argument “`$variables`”, and you need to typeset it to an `array` for this to work.

Comment: Does it look to you like I'm doing something wrong with the regex to get the name? Right now I'm not getting to the actionSection method. I put a commented out version of the original in my question.

Comment: I’m not sure what that means - is the code above your route or not?

Comment: Before implementing your change, hitting /actions/api/element/section/name/triviaQuestions/ will trigger actionSection($name) with $name='triviaQuestions'.   However if I use the above route (/api/test/triviaQuestions) I get a 404 - leading me to believe I've done something wrong in my routing.

Comment: @TylerWillingham Ah, there is a bug in your route. Just updated my answer.